# Why is the route not recognized in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, php-7, laravel-7

I created a project locally and tried to upload it to a free hosting service called altervista.org.
If I call the main page it works correctly while if I call another page it gives me http 404 error.

[Link to the main page](http://matchreferee.altervista.org/Prog2/public/)
[Link to a secondary page](http://matchreferee.altervista.org/Prog2/public/firstpage)

The code of web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/firstpage', function () {
    return "Hello in firstpage";
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks to me like the index.php entrypoint of laravel is not being called. Does it work locally?

Comment: "Ciao ciao micio micio". :) It [works](https://i.imgur.com/OomHps8.png). You have to set rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel doesn't work out of the box on sub folders. In order to get it working as-is, you have to host it on your document root (http://matchreferee.altervista.org/). If that's not possible, you can search on how to host laravel on a sub folder.